# Flutter webview is not showing image even thou it's so simple html

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I am making a Flutter app, and I am using webview here.
It all goes fine but when it comes to image, it just fails.
Other text contents are all fine.

I tried several things but all failed.
You can replicate the test by [this url](https://challeybiz.kr/appview/?kind=notice&id=1&uid=11&token=KWSd3drfll9r8Yn)
It appears fine from the browser but images never appaer only in flutter webview

This is my [flutter code](https://github.com/challeyJJ/challey202212/blob/main/viewWebPage.dart) for the webview

Comment: if it is really simple HTML, provide the whole HTML instead of ...
and also please include your flutter code.
thanx

Comment: Thanks I added flutter code up there by github, and also I provided html page by url (You can view the source HTML). Thanks for yor interest, and please help me. I've been stuck on this for 3 days in a row

Comment: Ooops I haven't made the flutter code publicly available. How fool I was. I just made it accessible. Please help, any one with any idea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. It was because the image source was referred as "http:". I just put the following tag and it solved like a charm

Comment: What following tag?